# CSS wont let my inline style override the class on select box

Tags: css

I want to use font-family:Arial Narrow; on this SELECT, but for some reason it will not let me override the font-family.

I can change size, color etc etc but not family, why?

```
            <select multiple 
                ng-options="item as item._id + ' - ' + item.name for item in vm.expenseCategory track by item._id"
                ng-model="vm.selectedExpense" 
                style="font-family:'Arial Narrow'!important; font-size:12px;" 
                class="startField ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
            </select>
```

Its almost like it ignores !important - I really dont understand this at all.

Here is Chrome:

[image]

Is there a rule that you cannot change the font-family on select boxes or?

Comment: Select boxes are rendered by the OS, not by the browser. The browser just passes styles whatever it can, hoping that the OS will render correctly. Many people use jQuery plugins for that reason.

Comment: Ahh so select just dont allow the font family to be changed. Ok - strange that you can change font family on the individual options, but not on the select box itself.

Comment: Give me a live link if you have.I think some script is over write it again. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can change font-family of any html elements to whatever font you like as long as that font-family is available. The `Arial Narrow` font is appropriate property of Microsoft Corporation therefore it is available in Windows OS by default. If you open your page in browsers that run on Windows OS then it will render properly since browsers rely on underlying OS font for rendering. For other OS, you need to make `Arial Narrow` font available by:

- Installing `Arial Narrow` to your machine
- Or host `Arial Narrow` font yourself in server then your browser will parse `Arial Narrow` font when it loads your page (pretty much the same way as Google font does)

```css
body * {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  /*
  font-size: 36px;
  color: red;
  */
}

/* Comment this selector if you uncomment font-size: 36px;
  color: red; in body * {} selector so you can test
 with inline style in your html markup
*/
#my-select-only * {
  font-family:'Arial Narrow';
}
```

```html
<select id="my-select-only" multiple 
                ng-options="item as item._id + ' - ' + item.name for item in vm.expenseCategory track by item._id"
                ng-model="vm.selectedExpense" 
                style="font-family:'Arial Narrow'!important; font-size:12px;" 
                class="startField ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
                <option>Apple</option>
                <option>Orange</option>
            </select>
```

Updated: Because you have set up somewhere in your css file `* { font-family: "Roboto"}` so it has more specificity and will override your inline style although you specify `!important`. I made a slight change in this code snippet and it renders fine with your desired font

Comment: As you can see on the image from Chrome, it refuse to change the font from "Roboto" (a font from the CSS) to "Arial Narrow" which is a font I use many other places.  But its only with this select, and its only the font-family.  How come I can change font-size and color and font-weight etc.. but not font-family?

Comment: if I follow your solution I will change the font of all selects on the entire website. And I dont need that, I only need to change this one select to a slimmer font because the content in the options is very wide. So what I need is to override the website CSS with an inline style.   And if what you say is true, how come I can override size and color and weight?

Comment: Give your select an id then you will not touch to all other elements in your html document like I did, run code snippet again and check it

Comment: You can override size and color because you have not set up those properties in `* { font-family: "Roboto"}`. You can uncomment my code `body * {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  /*
  font-size: 36px;
  color: red;
  */
}` to test for it. You are no longer able to override color and font-size of your select tag with inline style

Answer (score 0):

You should use `font` like this:

Replaces

> **font-family**: "Arial Narrow" !important;

By

> **font-family**: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;

Comment: This does not answer OP's question.